# In mongodb aggregation where to apply sort before lookup or after lookup?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am writing an aggregation query where i want to perform a join in MongoDB between two collections and for that i am using $lookup, now my question is does $lookup change order of results by sort or not ?? because if it does that then i need to put my sort after $lookup and if not then i can use it before $lookup ??

My code is given below

```
brandmodel.aggregate(
     {$project: { '_id':0, 'brand_id': 1, 'brand_name':1, 'brand_icon':1, 'banner_image': 1, 'weight': 1} },
     {$lookup: {from: "student_coupons",localField: "brand_id",foreignField: "brand_id",as: "coupons"}},
     {$unwind : "$coupons"},
     {$sort: {weight: -1, "coupons.time_posted": -1}}, // SHOULD I WRITE THIS BEFORE LOOKUP OR AFTER LOOKUP
```

Comment: Good question, I must admit I am unsure. What makes me unsure is whether or not $unwind would actually unsort the documents

Comment: `$lookup` and `$unwind` will not change order so you should use `$sort` before `$lookup` stage

Comment: Considering that MongoDB would multi-thread an $unwind do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @ShaishabRoy are you sure about that ??

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB 3.6, the $lookup has a more expressive way where you can access the fields of the source document and do further pipeline operations within the $lookup stage. See [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#syntax)

As an example,

```
db.movies.aggregate([
{ $match : { _id : ObjectId("573a1390f29313caabcd414c")} },
{ $lookup : {from: "comments", 
 let: {'id' : '$_id' },
 pipeline: [
 { $match : { '$expr': { '$eq': [ '$movie_id', '$$id' ] } }},
 { $sort: {'date': -1} }
 ],
 as:  "comments"
  }
 }   
])
```

You have to declare any fields you want from the source collection in the `let` , do the matching as required (This is optional). Then you can use the `pipeline` stages that you need to apply in the collection being looked up.

Answer (score 0):

See it totally matters on the situation. I will explain for you in different cases.

Case 1 - If the sort field is of primary collection.
Solution - If the field on which you were using $sort stage than you can use it before `$lookup`.

Case 2 - If the sort field is of secondary collection.
Solution - If the field is of secondary collection than, you are bounded to use `$sort` stage after the lookup.

Case 3 - If the sort field is not in the array on which you are using `$unwind`.
Solution - Than you can use the sort before `$unwind` stage.

Case 4 - If you are using a let lookup.
Solution - Use `$sort` stage inside the pipeline.

Case 5- If the sort field is of an array on which you are using `$unwind`.
Solution - Than you have to use the $sort stage after `$unwind` stage.